# Php Using a checkbox to pull multiple columns from my sql

Tags: php, html, sql

I currently am able to pull the equipment name column from my table and input it into my av_events SQL. But I would like to be able to pull the serial column as well to put in my av_bookings table equipment column as it is unique identifier.

Here I am doing it but I would like to be able to do it with just one checkbox

Appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<table>
<?php while ($av_inventory = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['equipment']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['product']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['serial']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['current_location']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['status']); ?></td>
      <td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $av_inventory['equipment'];?>">
          <input name='checkbox2[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $av_inventory['serial'];?>"></td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

---

```php
$equipArray = implode(', ', $_POST['checkbox']);
$implodeArray = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox2']);
$explodeArray = explode(',', $implodeArray);

$_SESSION['location'];
$_SESSION['logins'];

$sqllogin = "INSERT INTO av_events";
$sqllogin .= "(event_name, equipment, site, engineer_name, vp_present, date_time_from, date_time_to)";
$sqllogin .= " VALUES (";
$sqllogin .= "'". $eventName. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $equipArray. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $_SESSION['location']. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $_SESSION['logins']. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $vpPres. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $dateFrom. "',";
$sqllogin .= "'". $dateTo. "'";
$sqllogin .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqllogin);

foreach ($explodeArray as $serialNumber){
    $sqllogin = "INSERT INTO av_bookings";
    $sqllogin .= "(event_name, equipment, site, engineer_name, date_time_from, date_time_to)";
    $sqllogin .= " VALUES (";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $eventName. "',";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $serialNumber. "',";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $_SESSION['location']. "',";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $_SESSION['logins']. "',";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $dateFrom. "',";
    $sqllogin .= "'". $dateTo. "'";
    $sqllogin .= ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sqllogin);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could combine the information, then split it again afterwards. As a very rough guide:

```
<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $av_inventory['equipment'],'|', $av_inventory['serial'];?>"></td>
```

Then

```
$equipArray =[];
$explodeArray = [];
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $combined) {
  $split = explode('|', $combined);
  $equipArray[] = $split[0];
  $explodeArray[] = $split[1];
}
```

Then proceed as before.